# Decoding JSON to a class based on the value of another JSON key

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I am trying to work with a REST API that returns a JSON document who's structure depends on the value of a property named `type`.

I have defined the main class as follows:

```kotlin
@Serializable class Interaction(
    val type: Byte,
    val data: InteractionData? = null
)
```

The structure of `InteractionData` depends on the value of `type`. This is currently an interface that the four possible structures inherit from.

If `type` equals `2`, `data` should be a class named `ApplicationCommandData`:

```kotlin
@Serializable class ApplicationCommandData(
    val id: String,
    val name: String
): InteractionData
```

If `type` equals `3`, `data` should be a class named `MessageComponentData`:

```kotlin
@Serializable class MessageComponentData(
    val custom_id: String
): InteractionData
```

How can I make it so that the `data` property is serialised as the correct class based on the value of the `type` property?

I have tried setting the `data` property to `@Transient`, checking the value of `type`, and creating a new variable with `@SerialName` set to data inside of the class `init` block but `@SerialData` is not valid for local variables.

Comment: Have a look through the docs on ['closed polymorphism'](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#closed-polymorphism). EDIT: I've had a closer look, and I don't think there's a built-in solution for what you need.

Comment: Since you're working with JSON you can try using [content based polymorphic deserialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/v1.4.1/docs/json.md#content-based-polymorphic-deserialization)

Comment: @aSemy Will try this and let you know how I get on, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: skip to the full example at the bottom

#### Problem summary

You have a polymorphic class, and the type is determined by a property *outside* of the class.

```json
{
  "type": 2,  <- extract this
  "data": {   <- determined by 'type'
    "id": "0001",
    "name": "MEGATRON"
  }
}
```

Kotlinx Serialization provides the tools to handle this - but they need some assembly.

#### JSON content based polymorphic deserialization

Since you're working with JSON this is possible using [content based polymorphic deserialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/v1.4.1/docs/json.md#content-based-polymorphic-deserialization).

Here's an initial implementation, but there's a flaw...

```kotlin
object InteractionJsonSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Interaction>(
  Interaction::class
) {
  override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<out Interaction> {

    // extract the type from the plain JSON object
    val type = element.jsonObject["type"]?.jsonPrimitive?.intOrNull

    println("found InteractionData type: $type")

    return when (type) {
              // can't specify the type of InteractionData
      2    -> Interaction.serializer()
      3    -> Interaction.serializer()
      else -> error("unknown type $type")
    }
  }
}
```

It's not possible to select a specific serializer, because `Interaction` doesn't have a type parameter, so let's add one.

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Interaction<T : InteractionData?>( // add a type parameter
  val type: Byte,
  val data: T? = null
)
```

Now the Kotlinx Serialization plugin will [generate a serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/v1.4.1/docs/serializers.md#plugin-generated-generic-serializer) that accepts a serializer for `T: InteractionData`. We can update `InteractionJsonSerializer` to make use of this.

```kotlin
object InteractionJsonSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Interaction<*>>(
  Interaction::class
) {
  override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<out Interaction<*>> {
    val type = element.jsonObject["type"]?.jsonPrimitive?.intOrNull

    println("found InteractionData type: $type")

    return when (type) {
              // now the type can be specified
      2    -> Interaction.serializer(ApplicationCommandData.serializer())
      3    -> Interaction.serializer(MessageComponentData.serializer())
      else -> error("unknown type $type")
    }
  }
}
```

#### Complete example

Here's a complete, runnable example, with all the imports.

I made a couple of tweaks to your code.

- I made `InteractionData` a [sealed interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html), because it seemed appropriate
- I converted the classes to [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html), so Kotlin generates a nice `toString()`.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.DeserializationStrategy
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonElement
import kotlinx.serialization.json.intOrNull
import kotlinx.serialization.json.jsonObject
import kotlinx.serialization.json.jsonPrimitive

fun main() {
  val interactionType2 =
    Json.decodeFromString(
      InteractionJsonSerializer,
      /*language=JSON*/
      """
        {
          "type": 2,
          "data": {  
            "id": "0001",
            "name": "MEGATRON"
          }
        }
      """.trimIndent()
    )

  println(interactionType2)

  val interactionType3 =
    Json.decodeFromString(
      InteractionJsonSerializer,
      /*language=JSON*/
      """
        {
          "type": 3,
          "data": {
            "custom_id": "abc123"
          }
        }
      """.trimIndent()
    )

  println(interactionType3)
}


@Serializable
data class Interaction<T : InteractionData?>(
  val type: Byte,
  val data: T? = null
)

sealed interface InteractionData

@Serializable
data class ApplicationCommandData(
  val id: String,
  val name: String
) : InteractionData

@Serializable
data class MessageComponentData(
  val custom_id: String
) : InteractionData


object InteractionJsonSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Interaction<*>>(
  Interaction::class
) {
  override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<out Interaction<*>> {
    val type = element.jsonObject["type"]?.jsonPrimitive?.intOrNull

    println("found InteractionData type: $type")

    return when (type) {
      2    -> Interaction.serializer(ApplicationCommandData.serializer())
      3    -> Interaction.serializer(MessageComponentData.serializer())
      else -> error("unknown type $type")
    }
  }
}
```

##### Output

```
found InteractionData type: 2
Interaction(type=2, data=ApplicationCommandData(id=0001, name=MEGATRON))
found InteractionData type: 3
Interaction(type=3, data=MessageComponentData(custom_id=abc123))
```

##### Versions

- Kotlin 1.7.21
- Kotlinx Serialization 1.4.1